# Joining multiple tables results in duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

There are tow tables (Customer & Feedback) that have different information. The following query is almost correct, except that it results in duplicate rows.  I only need unique rows as par customerId and NO for null value.

I tried the GROUP BY clause at the end but it gives error.

```
Select C.CustomerId, 
       C.FirstName, 
       C.LastName, 
       (SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN F.Id != null or F.Type = 'Query' 
                         THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS NVARCHAR(50))) as Query,
       (SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN F.Id != null or F.Type = 'Feedback' 
                         THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS NVARCHAR(50))) as Feedback
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN Feedback F on  F.CustomerId= C.CustomerId
```

[image]

```
Select * from Customer
```

[image]

```
Select * from Feedback
```

[image]

As Result I want to display only single row by customerId and to join the feedback table data like below...
[image]

Comment: please post the data instead of images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You May Try either of the Below

```
SELECT
    C.*,
    Query = CASE WHEN PVT.Query IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END,
    Feedback = CASE WHEN PVT.Feedback IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    FROM Customer C
        LEFT JOIN  FeedBack
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX(Id)
                FOR
                [Type] IN
                (
                    [Query],[Feedback]
                )
            )Pvt
            ON PVT.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

or Simply

```
SELECT
    C.*,
    Query = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FeedBack WHERE CustomerId = C.CustomerId and [Type]='Query') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END,
    Feedback = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FeedBack WHERE CustomerId = C.CustomerId and [Type]='Feedback') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    FROM Customer C
```

To Make it more Dynamic ou may Try this

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [Type]),
        QRY = LTRIM(RTRIM([Type]))+' = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FeedBack WHERE CustomerId = C.CustomerId and [Type]='''+LTRIM(RTRIM([Type]))+''') THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END'
        FROM FeedBack
)
SELECT
    @SQL = 'SELECT
    C.*'
    +SUBSTRING(','+L.List,1,LEN(L.List)-1)
    +' FROM Customer C'
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            QRY + ', ' [text()]
            FROM CTE
                WHERE RN = 1
                FOR XML PATH('')
    )L(List)

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Please Refer this [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/367a1/1) for detailed example

Comment: Your simply query is just awesome, but can we make this dynamic. Suppose feedback table got a complaint in type then ? I don't believe to modify the sp again and again. Check this image... https://prnt.sc/koiop8

Comment: PIVOT is a Static Query, If you wish to make it dynamic then you will have to use a Query String

Comment: I'm not talking about the first query. 2nd one is cool but can you check the image link and think on that.. https://prnt.sc/koiop8

Comment: In both cases, you will have to use Query string since it involves adding New Columns

Comment: I don't know how to use Query String in Sql query? Could you please ad new solution.

Comment: @SunilAcharya I've updated the solution with one more answer. Please check

Answer (score 1):

```
Select C.CustomerId, 
       C.FirstName, 
       C.LastName, 
       sum(case when F.Type = 'Query' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 as Query,
       sum(case when F.Type = 'Feedback' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 as Feedback
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN Feedback F on  F.CustomerId= C.CustomerId
GROUP BY C.CustomerId, C.FirstName, C.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query using subquery:

```
    select *,case when query=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as query, 
case when feedback=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as feedbackfrom
(select CustomerId, firstname,lastname,
        sum(CASE WHEN Type = 'Query' 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Query,

        sum(CASE WHEN Type = 'Feedback' 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as Feedback from Customer C
        LEFT JOIN Feedback F on  F.CustomerId= C.CustomerId
group by CustomerId, firstname,lastname)a
```

Answer (score 0):

use `case when`

```
Select C.CustomerId, 
       C.FirstName, 
       C.LastName, 
       case when sum(case when F.Type = 'Query' then 1 else 0 end) > 0  then 'Yes' else 'NO' end as Query,
    case when   sum(case when F.Type = 'Feedback' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'Yes' else 'NO' End as Feedback
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN Feedback F on  F.CustomerId= C.CustomerId
GROUP BY C.CustomerId, C.FirstName, C.LastName
```

Comment: Actually It's giving the output but I'm expecting simple solution.

Comment: @SunilAcharya this query just contain just a join and case when is anything complex here :)

Comment: Simple query was given by @Jayasurya Satheesh but I expecting more dynamically by type from feedback table. Check this image https://prnt.sc/koiop8

Comment: @SunilAcharya could you please check query plan of both query then you will get which one is more simple

Comment: your second query is coll but need to make dynamic result for type from feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select c.CustomerId,
       c.FirstName,
       c.LastName,
       case when q.CustomerId is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end Query,
       case when f.CustomerId is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end Feedback,
from Customers c
left join (select customerId from Feedback where Type = 'Query' ) q on c.CustomerId = q.CustomerId
left join (select customerId from Feedback where Type = 'Feedback' ) f on c.CustomerId = q.CustomerId
```